# RPi2 starts but no display

Tags: boot, pi-2, display

I have an RPi2 that was working fine until I tried to boot it an hour ago. The red light is steady and the green light continually flashes, but nothing appears on my monitor.

I use an HDMI-to-VGA converter with my Pi, and when I was putting it away this morning I accidentally dropped it ~3 feet onto the floor. I wouldn't think that this should make it stop working, and I'm not able to test whether this is indeed the problem because I don't have any HDMI displays available.

I don't think the SD card is the problem, since Windows 10 can read it OK. Any idea what might be causing the problem?

EDIT: The RPi doesn't show in the list of devices connected to my home network even when I connect it to Ethernet. So maybe the display adapter isn't the problem and I should try reformatting the SD card? I had to put tape on the SD card holder because the spring inside seems to be broken, but it was still working until now and I'm not seeing 4 flashes so I assume that it's not the problem either.

Comment: Is the green led flashing in a pattern?

Comment: Not that I can tell, it seems to make a lot of tiny flashes and occasionally some big ones.

Comment: @tjohnson If it is flashing irrationally, then it's probably booting. The RPi is pretty tough, especially with drops, so I doubt the drop would break it, I've thrown my buddy's Pi down some stairs and it worked fine afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like the SD card was corrupted since reformatting it fixed the problem. The way I worded my question it's not clear, but it was the adapter that I dropped, not the Pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was evidently that the SD card had come loose while the Pi was still running and must have gotten corrupted. I reformatted it and installed NOOBS on it again, and everything is working now. I put a piece of electrical tape over the SD card to keep it in.

EDIT: I continued experiencing problems with my Pi after this which I thought were related to the SD card. It turned out that the problem was the cheap HDMI-to-VGA converter that I was using, which was functioning unreliably. After cutting the converter open and soldering a loose wire, my Pi worked again and I haven't had any problems with it since.